# get_fields foreach Дублируются данные

Tags: php, wordpress

```
    add_action('init', function (){
    register_post_type('objects', array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'               => 'Наши объекты',
            'singular_name'      => 'Объект', 
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить новый',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавить новый объект',
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактировать объект',
            'new_item'           => 'Новый объект',
            'view_item'          => 'Посмотреть объект',
            'search_items'       => 'Найти объект',
            'not_found'          =>  'Объектов не найдено',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине объектов не найдено',
            'parent_item_colon'  => '',
            'menu_name'          => 'Объекты'

          ),
        'public'             => false,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-sticky',
        'supports'           => array('title')
    ) );
});

function getObjects(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'post_type'   => 'objects',
    );

    $objects = [];

    foreach(get_posts($args) as $post){
        $objects = get_fields($post->ID);
        $objects['name'] = $post->post_title;
        $objects[] = $objects;
    }

    return $objects;
}
```

Нужно получить значение дополнительного поля (Advanced Custom Fields). По итогу выдает только последний один массив в таком виде:

```
Array
(
    [img] => http://vent-test.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/box3-ph.png
    [name] => TUTU
    [0] => Array
        (
            [img] => http://vent-test.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/box3-ph.png
            [name] => TUTU
        )

)
```

Должно быть так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [img] => http://vent-test.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/box3-ph.png
            [name] => TUTU
        )

)
```

И несколько штук. Помогите пожалуйста, долго не могу понять в чем ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эти три строчки должны выглядеть так

```
$object = get_fields($post->ID);
$object['name'] = $post->post_title;
$objects[] = $object;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо